# How to use RMQ and spring cloud stream for creating partition based producer?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I am trying to find example of spring cloud stream where it creates parition based producer for RMQ. I want to see how it will create binding for those queues as RMQ not natively support paritions for topic but it will create number of queues equivalent to number of partitions (I read this,I may be wrong). First I want to understand how to create producer using spring cloud stream on RMQ for partition based producer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class So43614477Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So43614477Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel output;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("fiz").setHeader("whichPart", 0).build());
        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("buz").setHeader("whichPart", 1).build());
    }

}
```

with properties...

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-key-expression=headers['whichPart']
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-count=2

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.required-groups=bar
```

I added the `required-groups` so you can see how the consumer queues are bound.

[image]

`foo` exhange bindings:

[image]

The expression can be any valid expression evaluated against the message (e.g. `payload.hashCode()`); it is then modded `%` against the partition count to determine the final partition.

Comment: Thanks , I was missing required-groups property. I was trying to send object and after setting spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processedDataChannel.content-type=application/json, its working fine. I will explore more on this and will keep reading docs too. So many questions right now in mind, but let me try few things first and refer lot of articles/posts/docs on this. Thank you again for getting me started!