# How to use RMQ and spring cloud stream for creating partition based consumer

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I am able to develop sample consumer using cloud stream and rabbit mq, if I have 3 partitions created by producer and if I deploy 3 instances in CF each one picks one queue and processes messages using index as documented.

Now question is if I have 10 partitions seems I need 10 instances, that is waste of resources, can we have one consumer listens to multiple partitions. The reason I have partition based producer because for me sequence of messages order for processing matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(TwoInputs.class)
public class So43661064Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So43661064Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener("input1")
    public void foo1(String in) {
        doFoo(in);
    }

    @StreamListener("input2")
    public void foo2(String in) {
        doFoo(in);
    }

    protected void doFoo(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    public interface TwoInputs {

        @Input("input1")
        SubscribableChannel input1();

        @Input("input2")
        SubscribableChannel input2();

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.group=bar-0
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1.destination=foo
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input1.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=foo-0

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.group=bar-1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.destination=foo
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input2.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=foo-1
```

This will consume from the 2 partitions created by the producer in the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614477/how-to-use-rmq-and-spring-cloud-stream-for-creating-partition-based-producer/43617131#43617131).

There's currently not a way to have a `@StreamListener` listen directly to 2 partitions.

**EDIT**

Here is another way, using `exchange->exchange` binding...

**Producer**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class So43614477Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So43614477Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel output;

    @Autowired
    private AmqpAdmin admin;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-count}")
    private int partitionCount;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination}")
    private String destination;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.partitionCount; i++) {
            String partition = this.destination + "-" + i;
            TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange(partition);
            this.admin.declareExchange(exchange);
            Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(exchange).to(new TopicExchange(this.destination))
                    .with(partition);
            this.admin.declareBinding(binding);
        }

        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("fiz").setHeader("whichPart", 0).build());
        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("buz").setHeader("whichPart", 1).build());
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-key-expression=headers['whichPart']
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partition-count=2
```

**Consumer**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So43661064Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So43661064Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void foo1(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=bar
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=foo-0,foo-1
```

The partitions from the primary exchange are routed to the partition exchange and the consumer gets a list of exchanges to bind his queues to.

You could pass that list in on the command line.

Comment: As you said this is one way, let me know if there are any other more elegant ways..but this works. Thinking if we can dynamically change number of partitions that itself I am not sure but...Thank you!

Comment: I edited the answer with another alternative. We've done some prototyping on auto-scaling rabbit consumers but it's a bit involved (dynamically allocating queues to consumer instances).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think it's a waste of resources? If your requirement dictates that you need stateful processing and you are splitting into multiple partitions, you will need N consumers for N partitions.

If you mix messages of different partitions on the same queue, your ordering would suffer. Unless you add some logic on your side to aggregate messages based on certain metadata.

Comment: Yes but what if my one consumer can process two partitions at same time with given cpu/heap.  This is how we achieve more throughput in normal messaging systems by using consumer concurrency, right? So what we are talking probably something like partition concurrency..